# Accepting only letters as input

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is supposed to only accept letters (for example Jack would be accepted, and jack1 would not be accepted).

It prompts the user for their first and last name then stores them. Once I had written the code for the first name, I tested it to see if I had written the code correctly for the first name, but it kept giving me [this error](http://prntscr.com/avuru3) .

In the answers can you please show how to make this work with only numbers being allowed?

**Code**

```
import random

operators = ["+", "-", "*"]


def greeting(first_name, last_name):
  print ("Hello", first_name + " " + last_name)
  Play = input('Are you ready to begin?')
  if Play == 'yes':
    print("Great", first_name + ", lets begin")
  else:
   greeting(first_name, last_name)



def Players_input():
  print ("Welcome to the Arithmetic Quiz")
  first_name = input("Please enter your first name: ")
  if all(x.isalpha() or x.isspace() for x in first_name):
    last_name = input("Please enter your last name: ")
    greeting(first_name, last_name) 
  else:
    print("Only alphabetical letters and spaces: no")

Players_input()

score = 0                                                        
for i in range(10):                              
    first_number = random.randint(1,12)        
    second_number = random.randint(1,12)                
    op = random.choice(operators) 


    print (first_number, op, second_number, " = ?")
    users_answer = int(input())

    if op == "+":
        right_answer = first_number + second_number
    elif op == "-":
        right_answer = first_number - second_number   
    elif op == "*":             
        right_answer = first_number * second_number       

    if users_answer == right_answer:
        print("Well Done!")
        score += 1
    else:
        print ("Sorry but thats the wrong answer, the right answer is: " + str(right_answer) + ". Better luck next time")

print (first_name, "Your final score in the Arithmetic Quiz is", str(score), "out of 10")
```

Comment: you should not say 'please help' three times and then just dump code and say 'Fix the error'. You need to come up with a coherent question in order to get a coherent answer.

Comment: Don't you understand that `first_name` is a local variable of the `Players_input` function?

Comment: Please don't post your errors as pictures. Use code formatting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for the first problem:

You never defined first_name *outside* of `Players_input`. This value is just stored inside the function, and get's deleted afterwards. (more about this in [the link added by gjttt1](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html))
There are two ways to solve this:

- You could make first_name global. But this is a bad style, so I wouldn't use this option. You would add `global first_name` at some point in `Players_input`, before it is written to (so either before or directly after the first print call)
- You could return first_name, this is the preferred way. Add a `return first_name` at the end of `Players_input`, and replace `Players_input()` with `first_name = Players_input()`.

The answer to the second problem:

Just use this function instead of `int(input())` (replace this line with `int_input()`):

```py
def int_input(prompt="", error_message="You didn't enter an integer!"):
    while True:  # repeat this until the function returns
        inp = input(prompt)  # get the input after autputting the prompt.
        try:  # Try to...
            return int(inp)  # turn it into an integer. If it works, return it.
        except ValueError:  # If it didn't work, it raised a ValueError. In this case...
            if error_message:  # print the error_message if it is not "", false or None.
                print(error_message)
```

Then you have a third problem: You should just use **lowercase letters** in function names, to distinguish them from classes. This is just about your style, but it'll certainly help to develop a good, clear coding style.

I hope I could help,

CodenameLambda

Comment: Thanks CodingLambdas, I've got my code working and doing what I want. :)

Answer (score 1):

The first_name variable is out of scope when you are trying to use it. It belongs to the Players_input() function.

[Read this article on scoping to get more of an idea of what is happening](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error. It's telling you that the `first_name` variable is not defined. This is because it is a local variable in the `Players_input` function and cannot be used elsewhere. Variables that are defined inside a function are put on the stack in memory and are destroyed when that stack frame is pushed off the stack. You call this 'going out of scope'.

I recommend that you look up information about the scope of variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare first_name=('hi') earlier in the code and then when you call it in as an input function you can write it like:

`first_name=str(input('Please enter your first name: '))`

Comment: Changing the type to a string does *nothing* (because input *already* returns a string), and does *nothing* to solve the problem, the variable goes still out of scope. And the parenthesis are redundant aswell. And you *really* should surround the code with `\``, because it isn't displayed as code otherwise.